# Mex or Compile (mcc) Matlab function that uses toolkits

Tags: matlab, matlab-compiler

Environment:

- Matlab R2012a (I have access to others if necessary)
- All Toolboxes/Compiler installed
- Ubuntu 12.04 64bit and/or Windows 7 64bit

I am working with the source for a software package written in Matlab (unfortunately its proprietary so no code examples...sorry), and one function briefly uses the Control System Toolbox and the Signal Processing Toolbox.

I have no problem running the code on my personal computer because I have every toolbox installed, however I would like to compile (mex or mcc) JUST the function using those two toolboxes. The goal, of course, is to run the software on a machine without those toolboxes, while leaving the remaining code open to change.

According to matlab, they have no problem with you compiling code that uses almost any toolbox. Here is the list of toolboxes that support mcc compilation:
http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/supported/compiler_support.html

The problem arises in that mcc no longer allows compiling with the `-x` option to create a mex-ed version of the function, so I'm forced to create a C executable (maybe? hopefully not). This particular function takes large matrices as parameters (impractical to write as a command line argument) and returns a structure of cell arrays.

The only way around this (as I see it now) would be to write the arguments (large matrices) to the hard drive in a binary .mat file , have the compiled C binary read in the arguments, run the algorithm, and finally save the return values in another .mat for the parent thread to load back into memory.

This seems totally impractical. I would greatly appreciate alternative suggestions. Please let me know if anything here in unclear. Thanks in advance!

**[Edit 1]**  The codegen package does not support [tf.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html). It seems like this should be possible (and used to be possible with the `mex -x` option), but I'm at a loss. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Although you can't supply any code samples, it may help to know which toolbox functions are involved. If there are only a few (or, indeed, two) then, depending on their complexity, it may be more practical to just reimplement them.

Comment: Hmm... Well filtfilt and c2d should be fairly easy (c2d is really simple, if you look at its code); and there are a quite a few Butterworth C implementations floating around on the web. tf may be a bit difficult ... unless it's only used once, with constant inputs, in which case perhaps you can just store the output in a static array? Alternatively, perhaps you can [build a shared library](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/support/solutions/en/data/1-2Q3TJ5/) from your M-code.

Comment: **Control System Toolbox:** [tf.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html) and [c2d.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/c2d.html)  **Signal Processing Toolbox:**   [butter.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/butter.html) and [filtfilt.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/filtfilt.html) _markdown took a min_

Comment: @wakjah I'm trying to avoid rewriting these functions. Since matlab doesn't mind developer compiling their toolboxes, there must be an elegant solution that doesn't involve reinventing the wheel.

Comment: See the link in the previous comment; that should do what you need, I believe.

Comment: just to make sure I understand, you want to distribute your code to other MATLAB users who dont necessarily have the required toolboxes? So the code is to be run in MATLAB, not integrated into other applications?

Comment: @Amro Yes, the code is to be run in Matlab, but I'm not distributing it to the public. The goal is to modify the package so two of my co-workers can use the model without the toolboxes. Hopefully this doesn't step on Mathworks toes...were not developing toolbox dependent code, were simply trying to use the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

I think the reason `-x` is not supported anymore is the fact that Matlab now has a product called "coder", which converts `.m` files to `.c` files and can also create `.mex` files from "suitable" `.m` files using the option `-args` to specify the input arguments: http://www.mathworks.com/videos/generating-c-code-from-matlab-code-68964.html

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for. Hopefully my code is "suitable"... Thank you! I will try this right now.

Comment: Unfortunately one of the functions being used, [tf.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html), is not supported by codegen. I'm disappointed that `mcc` discontinued support for `-x` mex compilation. It certainly limits my ability to use this code. I've looked through a fair bit of documentation and it looks unlikely that it's even possible. Welcoming suggestions though. Thanks for the info anyway!